# SQLite Database is not being created

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
public class SampleDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sample.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "id";
    public static final String COL_2 = "name";


    public SampleDB(Context context) 
       {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);      
       }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL_2 + " TEXT)"
         );

    insertData(1,"abc");
    insertData(2,"def");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertData(int id, String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_1,id);
        cv.put(COL_2,name);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? I've written below code in onCreate() of MainActivity.

```
SampleDB mydb = new SampleDB(this);
```

P.S : Empty Database Schema is Created when I don't call insert and write getWritableDatabase() in Constructor.

Comment: Why do you drop the table on the onUpgrade function?

Comment: Drop the old version table and replace it with the new version table.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper

> The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() is called.

Updated:

Some general guidance dealing with problems like this:-

While developing and changing your database code is worth making sure you always start from a known point when testing by reseting the database. This can be done by:-

- Use "Device File Explorer" in Android Studio to browse to /data/data/{your package name}/databases and delete the files

Or

- Change the database version number in the constructor to go through the upgrade code (less nice)

Comment: So where do I write it?

Comment: Write what? You asked why your database is not being created, the answer I gave explains why it is not created unless you call the two functions which you found out yourself.
If explaining this behaviour is not the right answer then I suggest you ask the right question to solve your problem.